# How can I run trained agents in new Tensorflow session?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, openai-gym

I would like to train multiple agents (with possibly very different graphs, variables, ...) using OpenAI's Universe/gym.

I started with the [universe-starter-agent](https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent) code and adjusted the saver as to also dump the .meta files.

The process of recovering a trained Agent and using it to run inference seems very tricky.. What I'm currently doing:

- I added some variable names to the LSTMPolicy class in model.py:

```css
class LSTMPolicy(object):
    def __init__(self, ob_space, ac_space):

        ##ADDED NAME:##
        self.x = x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None] + list(ob_space), name = "input_pixels")

        for i in range(4):
            x = tf.nn.elu(conv2d(x, 32, "l{}".format(i + 1), [3, 3], [2, 2]))
        # introduce a "fake" batch dimension of 1 after flatten so that we can do LSTM over time dim
        x = tf.expand_dims(flatten(x), [0])

        size = 256
        lstm = rnn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(size, state_is_tuple=True)
        self.state_size = lstm.state_size
        step_size = tf.shape(self.x)[:1]

        c_init = np.zeros((1, lstm.state_size.c), np.float32)
        h_init = np.zeros((1, lstm.state_size.h), np.float32)
        self.state_init = [c_init, h_init]
        c_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm.state_size.c])
        h_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm.state_size.h])
        self.state_in = [c_in, h_in]
        ##ADDED NAME:##
        state_in_0 = tf.identity(c_in,name = "LSTM_state_in_0")
        state_in_1 = tf.identity(h_in,name = "LSTM_state_in_1")
        
        state_in = rnn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(c_in, h_in)
        lstm_outputs, lstm_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            lstm, x, initial_state=state_in, sequence_length=step_size,
            time_major=False)
        lstm_c, lstm_h = lstm_state
        x = tf.reshape(lstm_outputs, [-1, size])
        self.logits = linear(x, ac_space, "action", normalized_columns_initializer(0.01))
        ##ADDED NAME:##
        inference_logits = tf.identity(self.logits ,name = "inference_logits")
        self.vf = tf.reshape(linear(x, 1, "value", normalized_columns_initializer(1.0)), [-1])
        self.state_out = [lstm_c[:1, :], lstm_h[:1, :]]
        self.sample = categorical_sample(self.logits, ac_space)[0, :]
        self.var_list = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, tf.get_variable_scope().name)
```

- I then wrote this snippet to try and load the graph and use it for inference:

```css
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

save_path = "universe_dumps/logs/pong_model_test/train/model.ckpt-0"

input_frame = [np.random.rand(42,42,1).astype(float)]
initial_state = np.zeros([1,256])

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)) as sess, sess.as_default():
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(save_path+".meta",clear_devices=True)
    new_saver.restore(sess, save_path)

    variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='global')
    W = variables[0]

    graph = variables[0].graph #Is this the way to get a pointer to the graph??
    inference_op = graph.get_operation_by_name("global/inference_logits")
    state_in_0 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("global/LSTM_state_in_0")
    state_in_1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("global/LSTM_state_in_1")

    feed_dict = {"global/input_pixels:0": input_frame, state_in_0: initial_state, state_in_1: initial_state}

    logits, W = sess.run([inference_op, W], feed_dict = feed_dict)
    print(logits)
    print(W.shape)
```

Everything I tried so far gave me an empty list back for logits and the current snippet (above) is giving me errors:
"The name 'global/LSTM_state_in_0' refers to an Operation, not a Tensor."

Even if I got this to work, I'd have to adjust the code every time I change something to the architecture of my Agent's graph... So I'm thinking there must be an easier way to do this? Anybody who can help me out here?

Ideally, I would like to have a function load_model(path_to_model)
that starts up a session, loads everything that is needed, returns an object onto which I can call a .predict method of some sort so that I can feed a single numpy array (42,42,1) and get the logits out of the trained Agent...

Answer (score 0):

The following lines seem problematic:

```
state_in_0 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("global/LSTM_state_in_0")
state_in_1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("global/LSTM_state_in_1")
```

The problem is that `"global/LSTM_state_in_0"` is the name of an **operation**, rather than the name of a **tensor** (i.e. a particular output of an operation). Assuming that you're interested in the 0th output of these operations, you should append `":0"` to the names, and the correct code would be:

```
state_in_0 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("global/LSTM_state_in_0:0")
state_in_1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("global/LSTM_state_in_1:0")
```

Comment: I added those changes but now I get:  
"InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'global/Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [1,256]" in line:
logits = sess.run(inference_op, feed_dict = feed_dict)

I thought I was already doing that?

Comment: You're feeding three tensors: `"global/input_pixels:0"`, `"global/LSTM_state_in_0:0"`, and `"global/LSTM_state_in_1:0"`, but you don't seem to be feeding a tensor called `"global/Placeholder:0"`. Based on the code, I think this name corresponds to one of the `c_in` or `h_in` placeholders in your original program.

Comment: I changed model.py as follows:

`c_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm.state_size.c], name ="LSTM_cin") and h_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, lstm.state_size.h], name ="LSTM_hin")`

But now, when I run: 
`feed_dict = {"global/input_pixels:0": input_frame, 
                 "global/LSTM_cin:0": initial_state, 
                 "global/LSTM_hin:0": initial_state}

    logits = sess.run(inference_op, feed_dict = feed_dict)
    print(logits)`
the output for logits is None...

Comment: One of this things I still find fishy is that during training, several worker threads are used that update a 'local' copy of the graph and then push gradient updates to the global variable store once every X steps. Could this be the cause of my issue? (Since the global graph is never actually used for inference during training..)

Comment: OK, I finally found a solution that works by adding self.logits in LSTMPolicy to a collection and then running `inference_op = tf.get_collection("inference_logits_collection")[0]`

Still feels like there should be an easier way of doing this, but hey machine learning is supposed to be a little bit hard right? :p